# How to limit maximum number of NSInteger in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a table to show searchData in iOS with UISearchBar.

When i search with keywords, i retrieved data into NSMutableArray.
There is alot of data in NSMutableArray. 
I just want to show about 20 datas in tableView.
Normally i used data to show in tableview,

> return [self.myArrayData count];

It's show entire data from NSMutableArray.
I want to limit data count to show in tableView.

How can i limit that data count?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSInteger count = [self.myArrayData count];
if (count > 20) return 20;
return count;
```

Comment: Or shorter and more "1337": `return ([data count] > 20) ? 20 : [data count];`

Comment: @JustSid Compiler will optimize it to something like that anyway, but my version is more readable. My own solution would be to use a `MIN(A,B)` macro but since I'm not sure whether it's there by default I'm not using it in this answer :)

Comment: Thanks you for your two answers. :)

Comment: The `MIN` and `MAX` macros are defined in NSObjCRuntime.h, so they're always available.